# PhpBB3 External Auth

Tags: php, authentication, phpbb3

I have a website with an account system. I would like to use the authentication from my site on my phpbb board on the same domain. Currently, I authenticate the user and grab the userid from my phpbb database. I have made sure I get the correct userid.

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = '/forum/';
$phpEx = 'php';
include("/forum/common.php");
$admin = false;
$autologin = false;
$viewonline = false;
echo $user->session_create($userId, $admin, $autologin, $viewonline);
```

This returns 1, which I am assuming is true and means the login was successful. When i go to the board I am logged in but I have no username or other user data. I have also then checked $user->data and it dumps all the user's data.[image]

Yes, there should be boards there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I let a custom auth method enabled. Reverting back to db_auth fixed it.